# Is there an event in Excel that runs when the application opens and before cells are calculated?

Tags: vba, events, calculation

I'm trying to prevent Excel from recalculating cells containing my UDFs (because they run slowly).

My aim is to cache all the cell values by address in a dictionary store when the application first loads, the UDF will return a value from the store if it exists, otherwise it'll do a full recalculation.

I've attempted using the `Workbook_Open()` event to gather all the formulas in the sheet when the application loads. My issue is that the `Workbook_Open()` event fires after excel tries to recalculate all the cells.

Is there an event that runs before `Workbook_Open()`?

Comment: Are you caching the results inside of the UDF?  A small example of how you're handling this would be useful here. The UDF still need to run at least once to populate the cache, so it's not clear what the problem is.  There's no event which runs before the Open event.  A work-around would be to modify your UDF so they exit immediately if you haven't already set a global "flag" (which you can set in the Open event, and then recalculate)

Comment: No, I'm caching the values in a public Dictionary store. The first time the cell runs it populates the store, this allows the cell to collect the value for consecutive times it calculates. My issue relates to when the workbook is first opened where the store will be empty, so I'd like to populate the store using the values in the sheet cells on the Open event in time for the UDF to collect the values from the store when it calculates. The problem with that is that excel calculates the cell before it runs the Open event.